# Magento delete disabled products via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

How can delete I disabled or specific products directly from the Magento database tables?.

What will be the query which needs to run in phpmyadmin? Or which tables do I need to update for this?

Comment: Short answer; you can't do this directly from the database. If you do, you most likely f-up your Magento database (or at least clutter it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes direct in DB is a dangerous move.  Easiest way to delete disabled products programmatically is this;

This is assuming you are not using multistore where products could have different status in each store view.

Create a php file with this code in;

```
include_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); // This gives us the rights to delete


$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 1)) // only get disabled
->load();

foreach($collection as $_product) {
    echo 'Deleting: '.$product->getName().'<br />';
    $_product->delete();
}
```

Drop this code in Magento root direcory and call it via a browser.  For automation I would recommend putting it in your shell directory (dont forget to modify the path to app/mage) and call it by cron each night.